# Linux grep en condición if

Tags: linux, bash, script

estoy haciendo un pequeño Script en el cual estoy añadiendo el titulo de películas y exportándolo a un mismo archivo .txt.

Quiero controlar con un if y grep que si existe la misma palabra en el documento no añada el título al archivo. Pero me está dando problemas os dejo mi código:

```
function Add () {

read -p "TÍULO: " title
read -p "AÑO: " year
read -p "DIRECTOR: " director
read -p "PRODUCTORA: " prod

if [ grep -iq "${title}" bbdd_vc.txt ]; then

    echo "La pelicula ya existe en la base de datos."
else
    printf "TÍTULO: "${title}" \nAÑO: "${year}" \nDIRECTOR: "${director}" \nPRODUCTORA: "${prod}" \n\n" >> bbdd_vc.txt

    echo ""
    echo "$(tput setaf 2)"Añadido con éxito."$(tput sgr0)"
    echo ""
fi

cat bbdd_vc.txt

MENU
```

Si alguien me puede decir en que estoy fallando, me estoy iniciando en Linux. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te está dando problemas... ¿cuáles problemas?

Comment: @Sal Hola, al ejecutar el script nunca pasa por la condición true ni tampoco detecta si existe la misma palabra.

Comment: Hay varios errores ahi. La funcion no cierra, grep necesita de "comand substitution" entre $(comand), la keyworkd "function" esta deprecated, "Qué es eso de la palabra MENU con mayusculas al final?"

Comment: En otras palabras, 1) elimina la palabra "function", 2) usa grep de la forma [ $(grep -qi "patron a buscar" archivo) ], 3) Elimina el comando MENU si no lo vas a usar, 4) Sería bueno que en la pregunta pusieras el resultado del script haciendo enfasis donde fallo, 5) Comienza la funcion con minusculas (buena convención) y elimina espacio entre el nombre y los parentesis (no son necesarios)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba poniedo lo que evalua la condición **if** entre acentos graves " **`** "
de esta manera:

```
if `grep -iq "${title}" bbdd_vc.txt`; then
```

si te vuelve a dar problemas por favor siempre publica lo que arroja la consola ya que aveces por allí esta el comienzo de la solución al problema.